# `Gmisc` package: how to add italic to only part of text using the `glue` package?

Tags: r, plot, grid, italic, gmisc

Using the `Gmisc` package, how can I add italic to only part of text using the `glue` package? See the reprex below for details:

```r
library(Gmisc, quietly = TRUE)
library(grid)

grid.newpage()
txt <- "Just a plain box"
boxGrob(txt)
```

[image]

```r
grid.newpage()
txt <- expression(italic("Just a plain box"))
boxGrob(txt)
```

[image]

```r
grid.newpage()
txt <- paste("Just a", expression(italic("plain")), "box")
boxGrob(txt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So it seems the italic works only if used on the entire string and not when used inside paste as suggested on the package website here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Grid-based_flowcharts.html

We can alternatively use `bquote` (as also suggested): this seems to work.

```r
library(Gmisc, quietly = TRUE)
library(grid)

grid.newpage()
txt <- bquote(paste("Just a ", italic("plain"), " box"))
boxGrob(txt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, it seems incompatible with the `glue` package:

```r
library(Gmisc, quietly = TRUE)
library(grid)
library(glue)

grid.newpage()
txt <- bquote(italic("plain"))
txt
#> italic("plain")
# txt actually has length 2, not 1, so leads to an error
length(txt)
#> [1] 2
expr <- glue("Just a {p} box", p = txt)
expr
#> Just a italic box
#> Just a plain box
boxGrob(expr, p = txt)
#> Error in boxGrob(expr, p = txt): unused argument (p = txt)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be use `parse` like so:

```r
library(Gmisc, quietly = TRUE)
library(grid)
library(glue)

grid.newpage()
txt <- 'italic("plain")'
expr <- glue("Just~a~{p}~box", p = txt)
boxGrob(parse(text = expr))
```

[image]